# Disable ToolbarItem Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following in my page:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Run" Command="{Binding RunCommand}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

The command starts an async task.
I am trying to disable the control as long as the async task is still running by binding it to a boolean property as follows:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Run" Command="{Binding RunCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding MyBoolProperty}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

My issue is that there doesn't seem to be a "IsEnabled" property for ToolbarItem. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do using Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Note, I tried replacing "ToolbarItem" with a "Button" and failed miserably: "Object type Xamarin.Forms.Button cannot be converted to target type: Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem".

Comment: depending on the expected length of your operation if you run it on the UI thread the button remains in pressed state. it's an ugly hack and you shouldn't use it for network access since that can lock your app up for a very long period

Comment: Perhaps the source was updated, but now there is a [`IsEnabled` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.menuitem.isenabled?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_MenuItem_IsEnabled). Though, I can't still change the value once set.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After the help of William and Xamarin support, I was finally able to find how functionality works.

It is a bit counter intuitive as we expect to Enable/Disable the button (ToolbarItem), but we actually have to manage the state of the command that is bound to the button. Once we understand this pattern, it makes sense.

The Command object of type ICommand, has a CanExecute property (thank you William for pointing it out)
Now you don't want to access/use it directly unless it is for actually checking if the command can be executed or not.

Wherever you see fit in your code, to change the state of the command, you need to add the following line:

```
((Command)_myCommand).ChangeCanExecute();
```

This line will force the CanExecute property to be re-evaluated for the specified command.

I personally decided to add it where I track the inactivity as it made sense in my application.

```
public bool Inactive { 
    get { 
        return _inactive;
    } 
    set {
        if (_inactive != value) {
            _inactive = value;
            ((Command)_myCommand).ChangeCanExecute();
            OnPropertyChanged ();
        }
    }
}
```

In the View, there are no changes to be noted:

```
<ToolbarItem Text="Run" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

Now when you create the Command object is where the big work will be done. We usually use the single argument constructor as it is generally enough and it is where we define what our command does. Interestingly enough, there is a 2 parameter constructor as well where you can provide the function/action that determines the value of the CanExecute property.

```
_myCommand = new Command (async () => {
                                          Inactive = false;
                                          await Run();
                                          Inactive = true;
                                      },
                                      () => {
                                          return Inactive;
                                      });


public ICommand MyCommand {
    get { 
        return _myCommand;
    }
}
```

Edit: I know you that technically changing the value of Inactive should happen in Run(), but for demonstration purposes...

Comment: My code doesn't work with this sample. This really disable the button or just avoid to execute the code? Do you have a full sample of this implementation? Thanks.

Comment: It does both (disable the button & avoid to execute). What platform are you on? I've tested on iOS and Android. Also, I know there was an issue, when ToolbarItem's order was set to Secondary where you could not see the difference between enabled or not, but the code would still not execute if disabled.

Comment: I've added the property declaration for MyCommand to the answer to fully close the loop.

Comment: @LostBalloon How would you implement this pattern purely in c#? I am generating my ToolBar Item like this: 

ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("add", "plus.png", () =>
{
    CreateItem();
}));

Comment: before doing the add do a `var tbi = new ToolbarItem("add", "plus.png", () => { CreateItem(); });` and then `tbi.Command = ViewModel.MyCommand` where ViewModel is your view model from your binding context & then just `ToolbarItems.Add(tbi);` The rest should be very similar

Comment: I tried your approach, but it only disables the ToolbarItem. The Icon maintains visible.

Comment: Correct, this is the intended behaviour. Disabling, not removing which is the proper UX pattern for most cases. In the case you need to switch the available actions based on the context should normally be the only time you remove buttons to add different ones.

Comment: That said, here's what you were looking for: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20676/is-it-possible-to-hide-a-toolbaritem

Comment: I agree with @LostBalloon - the correct approach to this problem is what's described here (please note the specific comment in the link) 

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/182677/#Comment_182677

I believe it should be supported by framework too. Please vote for it here.
https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/258559-xamarin-forms-suggestions/suggestions/15508584-visibility-of-toolbaritems

Comment: @LostBalloon mentioned that there's a bug preventing secondary menu items reflect their visual state (be gray our or not). See my answer in the thread how to make the items visually be different.

Answer (score 2):

This example is to remove, not disable but might also be handy.

```
    ToolbarItem delToolbar;       

    ...

        delToolbar = new ToolbarItem
        {
            Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary,                
            Text = "delete",              
            Command = new Command(async () =>
            {                                       
                ToolbarItems.Remove(delToolbar);
            })
        };
        ToolbarItems.Add(delToolbar);
```

Answer (score 1):

What I've learned to do in these situations is as follows:

```
public Command RunCommand 
{ 
    get { return new Command(async() => await OnRunCommand()); }
}    

private bool _isRunning;

public async Task OnRunCommand() 
{
    if (_isRunning) return;
    _isRunning = true;

    // do stuff

    _isRunning = false;
}
```

The **downside**: this leaves the toolbar item in its normal state and users may continue to tap on it.

The **upside**: this won't allow simultaneous OnRunCommand tasks, which is good.

If you want to pursue disabling the button by showing a disabled image, you should create a renderer.

If you do not want to show the toolbar item while the task is running, consider removing the toolbar item from the page and re-adding it later.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that as a possible "worst case scenario" solution, but I'd really rather not break the user experience with the button. I considered giving a popup that tells them to be patient as the task is already running though I'd much rather be able to disable it. I was surprised at this very basic omission for an item that acts like a button.

Comment: ToolbarItem may have an IsEnabled BindableProperty in Xamarin Forms 1.3.0 now that I think of it. I would give that a try.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to be the case yet.

Comment: Xamarin Forms 1.3.2 pre-1 exposes a CanExecute property that can be used to visually disable the ToolbarItem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I tried it but for some reason I cant get the CanExecute property. (I checked here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31273/xamarin-forms-1-3-2-pre1-released and it should exist as you mentioned) I get the following exception: "Position 9:75. No Property of name CanExecute found" and I can't seem to find it in code either. Weird thing...

Answer (score 0):

LostBalloon's answer is correct in terms of using `CanExecute` command. But the problem I faced was that the `ToolbarItems` **visual state** didn't change. I want the secondary toolbar items (i.e. menu items) **gray out** when disabled (in other words when `CanExecute` returns false). Some authors was saying that this is a bug. May be it is a bug, but the following solution works for me.

### The result:

[image]

### To gray out disabled Toolbar items:

Set theme in your `Resources/layout/Toolbar.xml` file to `MyToolbarTheme`:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/MyToolbarTheme"
 />
```

Add the theme `MyToolbarTheme` in `Resources/values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/menu_item_color_selector</item>
    </style>
```

Now create a new file `Resources/color/menu_item_color_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="#000"/>
    <item android:color="#999"/>
</selector>
```

### Side notes:

1. You may use different parent themes, for example instead of `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` you can use `com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar`. Works either way.
2. Some authors reference to the attribute `actionMenuTextColor` for changing menu items font color, but this one didn't work for me (not sure why). Instead I was using `android:textColor` and it works.
3. You can use `android:background` in `Toolbar.xml` to set the background of the toolbar itself.
4. You can change the color of the **3 dots** by setting `colorControlNormal` in `MyToolbarTheme`:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#0FF000</item>
```

5. Any Android XML resource file you created in Visual Studio, must have build action `AndroidResource` and Custom Tool field set to `MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles` (set it is in property window of the file)
6. In addition to #5, the `Toolbar.xml` file must be referenced in `MainActivity.cs`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    ...
}
```

7. Make sure you are using `android:theme` tag in `Toolbar.xml`, not `android:popupTheme`. Not obviously why, but the `popupTheme` didn't work for me.